# Write to two applications at the same time

Tags: vim

Is it possible to type on your keyboard and have it write in two different applications at the same time? I would like to write in Vim and another application which gives me intellisense (smart autocompletion). I'm not sure how this would work. But it would be extremely nice to have.

Comment: I don't think that this will be an extremely nice to have because the two editors will act different on a keystrokes. A keystroke sequence that does autocompletion in one application may erase a word (or your hard disk)  when typed to the other application. That does not seem very useful to me. So what is your real problem? Do you want to use vim  with autocompletion, or do you use another editor and want some vim features to use? Or is it something completely different you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirectly, you might get close to what you want by writing to a file and have both vim and your other application setup to autoreload on changes to the file.

vim Can be configured to [autoreload](https://www.google.be/search?q=vim%20autoreload&rls=com.microsoft:nl-BE&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&gfe_rd=cr&ei=B_uDVOarKbDj8weB_II4&gws_rd=ssl) but it depends on your other application if it offers that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You could use terminator.  Open terminal, split it in half so that you have 2 terminals open.  Then open 2 different files using different applications, and use the "broadcast" feature on terminator.